# Facebook, check if user is a fan and logged in using PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-like

I have searched the Internet and SO for over a week, but have not managed to find anything yet so allow me to ask a question which has already been asked loads of time on SO, but for which none of the answers seem to be working for me.

I have a website and a Facebook page. On my website I have the usual Facebook "Like me" box. As I want to show some extra content to my fans when they visit the website - and encourage non-fans to become a fan - I would like to know if it is possible, via PHP, to:
1. Understand if the user is a fan
2. Understand if the user is logged into Facebook

What I would like to be able to do is send a PHP request to Facebook and receive one of the following three answers: "is a fan", "not a fan", "not logged-in/not a Facebook user".

In the first case I would show the fan-only content, in the secon case I would try to encourage the user to become a fan, while in the third case I would not do anything as I'm not sure the user is a Facebook user.

Please note:
1. I do not need any further identifying information
2. There is no app involved here, as users are fans of my page, although I could build one if necessary

Some answers on SO seem to point to this tutorial, but as my page is not an app, I cannot really use this solution:
http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/facebook-api-check-if-a-user-is-fan-of-a-facebook-page/20/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Facebook's APIs won't tell you if the user's logged in or if is a fan of your page until you make the user install your Facebook app (and for the likes you will need `user_likes` permission too).

The only kind of exception is that when you are running a page tab. At the time facebook embeds your content via an `<iframe>`, the `signed_request` POST parameter that comes with it will tell you if the user is a fan or not. You can read about the [signed request's here.](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/).

Comment: Here is an idea for Facebook, consider all fan pages as apps and thus allow them to "request" at least some information. Instead of sending "app-secret", you would send "fan-page-secret" and would then be able to retrieve a limited amount of data. Any Facebook devs reading SO?

Comment: There is some information you could get with app access tokens, mostly public things like user names, public feed data and such. Also keep in mind that since we are not paying anything to use their system (at least i don't), not exactly in the position of making demands. At the and of the they they have to answer their shareholders not even the their massive user base.

Comment: I'm definitely not complaining @complex857 :)